# SPARQL Query Printing Literal in Jena

Tags: java, sparql, jena, semantic-web, ontology

I am trying to write a query for this owl model.

```
:Sensor rdf:type owl:Class;
:hasId rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty,
                rdfs:domain :Sensor;
                rdfs:range xsd:int.
:MedicalCountainer rdf:type :owlNamedIndividual,
                            :Sensor;
                            :hasId "55"^^xsd:int .
```

I want to use sensor-id to retrieve the sensor name.
This is my query in Java, but I don't know why it doesn't print anything. I knew that my query is right because I will get the answer in Protégé.

```
String file = "C:/users/src/data.ttl";
Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel(file);
String queryString = "PREFIX : <http://semanticweb.org/sensor#>" +
                     "SELECT ?sensor" +
                     "WHERE {?sensor :hasId \"55"\^^<xsd:int>}";
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
try (QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model)) {
          ResultSet result = qexec.execSelect();
          for ( ; result.hasNext(); ) {
                  QuerySolution soln = result.nextSolution();
                  Resource r = soln.getResource("sensor");
                  System.out.println(r);
          }
}
```

Comment: You are querying for the variable "sensor". Then, you retrieve the literal for "Valr". Have you tried to retrieve the literal for "sensor" instead? That is, soln.getLiteral("sensor");

Comment: Actually, I notice that I have a major problem in my code. The loop doesn't run, that means 'result' is empty. I update my code, I can't figure what is the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of the literal in the SPARQL query is wrong. Either you use

1. a prefixed URI for the literal, i.e. `"55"^^xsd:int`, or
2. you put the full URI into angle brackets, i.e. `"55"\^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>`

but not a mixture of both.

And always prefer to add all PREFIX declarations to the beginning of the SPARQL query in order to ensure proper parsing across all SPARQL services:

```sql
PREFIX : <http://semanticweb.org/sensor#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?sensor
WHERE {
  ?sensor :hasId "55"^^xsd:int
}
```

Comment: I am using turtle, and I knew the first way you mention is the correct way but I'm getting  this error:
`org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException: Line 2, column 63: Unresolved prefixed name: xsd:int` 
However, the second way you mention is worked, but I just print null. Do you know, why?

Comment: Because you have to declare all prefixes in the beginning of the SPARQL query. Sometimes APIs/tools do provide some pre-defined prefixes, but to make it working everywhere, best practice is to add all prefixes that are used in the query: `PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> ` I added this also to my answer for future reference.

Comment: Thanks so much. Do you know why I am getting null? On protege I am getting the answer but here I am getting null for this query.

Comment: Because the only variable that you select is called `?sensor` and not `Varl`. Moreover, it is a resource and not a literal so it remains unclear why you call `getLiteral("Varl)` instead of `getResource("sensor")`

Comment: Thanks so much, It is first time I am using JENA. That's why I am so confused, and I don't have any help other than stackoverflow. I update my code